# kubernetes - resource limits exceeded

Tags: resources, kubernetes, cpu

I have a cluster running Kubernetes v1.6.7.

The VMs are :

`Distributor ID:  Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:    8.7
Codename:   jessie`

Kernel :
`3.16.0-4-amd64`

We have set cpu limits in deployments, however pods comsume cpu over this limit if they need to. Is there something am I missing ? Like a parameter in kubelet to enable this limit ? I haven't found anything about this problem.

For example, if I create the following deployment :

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stress
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: stress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        k8s-app: stress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: stress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stress
        image: progrium/stress
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["--cpu", "1"]
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "1Gi"
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "512Mi"`

On the node, this makes a CPU 100% used whereas it should be 50%.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give more details about how you limiting CPU, how did you check that pods consume CPU over limit?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question with the details.

Comment: Can you also tell how  you checked CPU load? Top, or using some monitoring etc.

Comment: With top and htop :  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                        
17096 root      20   0    7316     96      0 R 100,0  0,0   2:40.82 /usr/bin/stress --verbose --cpu 1

Comment: Kubernetes dashboard also tells me this pod has a cpu usage of 1 core.

Comment: Ok. Can you call `docker stats` to a container with your stress test? It have to show a limit of resource which Kubernetes set for that container.

Comment: The output is : CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
0cbb5f015100        99.46%              168 KiB / 1 GiB     0.02%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           0

Comment: please call `docker inspect $pod |grep CpuQuota` and `docker inspect $pod |grep CpuPeriod` and tell me result.

Comment: `"CpuQuota": 0,` and `"CpuPeriod": 0,`

Comment: Which Docker version you using? Can you also try to run a container manually like `docker run --cpu-period="50000" --cpu-quota="100000 progrium/stress --cpu 1" ` and check values by `inspect` and actual CPU usage?

Comment: I have the following warning : WARNING: Your kernel does not support CPU cfs period or the cgroup is not mounted. Period discarded.
WARNING: Your kernel does not support CPU cfs quota or the cgroup is not mounted. Quota discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comments to your question, where you can try to run docker container with CPU limit you getting:
`WARNING: Your kernel does not support CPU cfs period or the cgroup is not mounted. Period discarded. 
WARNING: Your kernel does not support CPU cfs quota or the cgroup is not mounted. Quota discarded.`

That mean your system's kernel build without support of CFS. Here is an [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22245) about it, right about 3.16.0-4-amd64 version.

You need to rebuild or update your kernel.

Here is how to update it from backports:

- Add mirror with backports:

  `$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list
  deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
  deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main`
- Update apt:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install a kernel from a backport repo:`sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-image-amd64`
- Reboot after instalation.